# Entity Framework core many to many insert in navigation properties failed?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I'm starting with ef core - code first, and I have simple asp.net console app im which I have 3 tables and 1 join table for many to many relationship. This is how tables looks like:

```
public class Kupac
 {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public String Ime { get; set; }
    public String Prezime { get; set; }
    public List<Racun> Racuni { get; set; }       
 }
public class Proizvod
 {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public String Naziv { get; set; }
    public float Cijena { get; set; }
    public List<ProizvodRacun> ProizvodRacun { get; set; }
 }
public class ProizvodRacun
 {
    public int ProizvodId { get; set; }
    public Proizvod Proizvod { get; set; }
    public int RacunId { get; set; }       
    public Racun Racun { get; set; }
    public int Kolicina { get; set; }
 }
public class Racun
 {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<ProizvodRacun> ProizvodRacun { get; set; }
    public int? KupacId {get; set;}
    public Kupac Kupac { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
 }
```

I know that I should use ICollection instead of List  but that's not problem right now I think. I have some data in tables "Kupac(Customer)" and "Proizvod(Product)". When I try to add something in this join table - "ProizvodRacun" I use this code:

```
using (MyContext context = new MyContext())
        {
            Kupac kupacc = context.Kupci.SingleOrDefault(k => k.Id == 2);
            Proizvod proizvod = context.Proizvodi.SingleOrDefault(p => p.Id == 5);
            Racun racun = new Racun();
            racun.Kupac = kupacc;
            ProizvodRacun proizvodRacun = new ProizvodRacun();
            proizvodRacun.Proizvod = proizvod;
            proizvodRacun.Racun = racun;
            proizvodRacun.Kolicina = 5;
            context.Add(proizvodRacun);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
```

And this works! But when I try to do the same thing in other way navigation properties are not added, but records in tables are!! The other way is this:

```
Racun racun = null;
            Kupac tempKupac = null;
            ProizvodRacun proizvodRacun = new ProizvodRacun();
            tempKupac = context.Kupci.SingleOrDefault(k => k.Id == kupac.Id);
            if (tempKupac != null)
            {
                if (tempKupac.Racuni != null)
                {
                    racun = context.Racuni.SingleOrDefault(r => r.Active == true);
                    if (racun != null)
                    {
                        proizvodRacun.Racun = racun;
                        context.Add(proizvodRacun);
                        context.SaveChanges();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        racun = new Racun();
                        racun.Active = true;
                        racun.Kupac = tempKupac;
                        racun.ProizvodRacun = new List<ProizvodRacun>();
                        proizvodRacun.Racun = racun;
                        context.Add(proizvodRacun);
                        context.SaveChanges();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    //FIRST TIME THIS CODE GET EXECUTED SO JUST WATCH THIS CASE
                    racun = new Racun();
                    racun.Kupac = tempKupac;
                    proizvodRacun.Proizvod = context.Proizvodi.SingleOrDefault(p => p.Id == products[i].Id);
                    proizvodRacun.Kolicina = j;// j -> option from code above that can't be seen...
                    proizvodRacun.Racun = racun;
                    context.Add(proizvodRacun);
                    context.SaveChanges();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Customer doesn't exist!");
            }
```

Please help me ...

Comment: What's the exact problem? Can you trim down the code to minimum reproducing the issue (and of course explain what the issue is:)

Comment: @IvanStoev The issue is in this "longer" code, you have comment in else statement to watch only that statement. The problem is that when that code is executed records are added in databse but navigation properties of entities are null. But when "shorter" code get executed navigation properties are there. Those 2 codes are so similar so I can't see a problem...

Comment: So by navigation properties you mean the collection (list) properties of the affected entities?

Comment: @IvanStoev One of navigation properties are those,yes.

Comment: Sorry, can't reproduce (EF Core 2.0). The navigation properties are not null and contain the `proizvodRacun` and `racun` objects.

Comment: how are the navigation properties configured? I can't see the problem, but I can't really imagine what you're trying to accomplish either.

Comment: @DevilSuichiro What do you think how are navigation properties configured ? I'm trying to browse through "Kupac"s "Racun"s because "Kupac" has list of "Racun" and I cannot do that because he's "Racun" is null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found problem, I had to use `.Include()` when I queried "Kupac" , to include its "Racun"s. The "Racun" was always there just it wasn't loaded.